# Clarifying behavior of unset

Tags: gun

I wanted to clarify my understanding of unset() or rather the behavior I am observing. I understand if I call unset() it replaces the value with a null (per the deleting data in Gun). So this is what I would like to confirm, assuming you've called unset():

1) When you call once() or on() it returns null for nodes which have been unset()

2) When you call Gun.obj.empty(table, '_') it returns false

I also tried setting the value of my set to null e.g.

`get('mylist').put(null)`

Which worked! I wanted to empty my set. However, the next time I added a new node my original set along with all of the original nodes were restored. I ended up writing the following to empty my set

```
this.context.once().map().once(data => {
    let key = data["_"]["#"];

    let node = this.context.get(key);
    if (node) {
        this.context.unset(node);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `.unset` tombstones (`null`) an item in the table, but not the table itself. Just so others are aware: `.unset` is community maintained inside of the GUN repo, and not maintained by me - so I may be wrong about its behavior OR the extension may be out of date.

`Gun.obj.empty({})` is just a utility to check if an object is empty or not. The 2nd parameter lets you pass it a property to ignore (like `'_'` which every GUN node has on it in the JS implementation).

**You are correct** though, that `gun.get('list').put(null)` should "clear out" the list, such that when you go to save data to it again (or call `.set(item)` to add an item) this should force/cause GUN to generate a **new** list/table/set/collection.

It is wrong behavior for it to "resurrect" the old list (unless another peer was trying to at the same time re-write to the old list at the same parent context), so this should be considered a bug that needs to be fixed. (Probably due to the old list ID being cached and not cleared from memory properly)